# Function with minimum sensitivity

Tags: complexity-theory, boolean-algebra

Let sensitivity be defined as in [Sensitivity and Block sensitivity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33798/sensitivity-and-block-sensitivity)

Is there an example of a boolean function in $n$ variables that depends on all $n$ inputs whose sensitivity is $O(\log n)$?

Is there an example of a boolean function in $n$ variables that depends on all $n$ inputs whose average sensitivity is $O(\log n)$?

Is there an example of a boolean function in $n$ variables that depends on all $n$ inputs whose sensitivity and average sensitivity is $O(\log n)$?

Comment: Note that the average sensitivity is at most the sensitivity, so if a function has sensitivity $O(\log n)$ then it also has average sensitivity $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tribes function](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=655) is the classical example of a transitive balanced function whose average sensitivity is $\Theta(\log n)$. Its maximal sensitivity is however $\Theta(n/\log n)$.

The addressing function is an example of a balanced function depending on all inputs which has sensitivity $\Theta(\log n)$ and average sensitivity $\Theta(\log n)$. It is simpler to describe this function as having an input of size $n + \log n$: the first $n$ bits describe a binary string $x$, and the last $\log n$ bits describe a number $i \in [1,n]$. The output of the function is $x_i$. At any point the function depends only on the $\log n$ bits of $i$ as well as the single bit $x_i$.

Comment: are there any other functions whose maximum sensitivity is $O(\log n)$?

Comment: Yes. There is a function which has sensitivity $\tfrac{1}{2}\log n + O(\log\log n)$ in Wegener, *The Complexity of Boolean functions*, at least according to this paper: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~kutin/publications/sens.iandc.pdf (page 4 middle).

Comment: So are such functions rare? Say if I find an example(after some hard work), would there be any use?

Comment: Unless it satisfies other coveted properties, I don't think it will be very interesting.

Comment: ah so it is common knowledge now? What other coveted properties that you are thinking?

Comment: You can ask a new question about it, and see what people have to say.

Comment: I posted a question in cstheory and let me see what response I get and after that I will respond.